# Bottle Server: removing routes

Tags: python, url-routing, bottle

I want to add and remove routes while my **bottle** server is running.

**My general question: Is there a proper way to remove routes?**

**In other words: How can I undo what I've done with `app.route`?**

In the following I desrcibe my problem in a more detailed way. Please don't waste your time reading it, if you know the answer to my general question.

This is a little demo script that describes how I'm working around my problem:

If calling **GET /add**: a *'Hello World' route* is added

If calling **GET /remove**: all routes with the same prefix like the *'Hello World' route* are changed to trigger a  **404 error**

```
import bottle
from bottle import redirect, abort

def addRoute():
    app.route('/route/hello')(lambda :'Hello World')
    print('Routes after calling /add:\n' + '\n'.join([str(route) for route in app.routes]))
    redirect('route/hello')

def removeRoute():
    prefix = '/route/hello'

    #making a list of all routes having the prefix
    #because this is a testfile there is only one rule that startswith prefix
    routes = [route for route in app.routes if route.rule.startswith(prefix)]

    #because there could be multiple routes with the same rule and method,
    #making a list without duplicates
    ruleMethodTuples = list(dict.fromkeys([(route.rule, route.method) for route in routes]))

    for ruleMethod in ruleMethodTuples :

        #Workaround: Overwriting the existing route with a 404
        #Here I'd prefer to make a statement that removes the existing route instead,
        #so the default 404 would be called
        app.route(ruleMethod[0], method = ruleMethod[1])(lambda **kwords: abort(404, 'Route deleted'))

    print('Routes after calling /remove:\n' + '\n'.join([str(route) for route in app.routes]))
    redirect('/route/hello')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = bottle.app()
    app.route('/add')(addRoute)
    app.route('/remove')(removeRoute)
    print('Initial routes:\n' + '\n'.join([str(route) for route in app.routes]))
    bottle.run(app, host = 'localhost', port = 8080)
```

So here is the output after starting and calling:

**/add**

**/remove**

**/add**

showing which **routes** are in **app.routes** after every call.

```
Initial routes:
<GET '/add' <function addRoute at 0x02A876A8>>
<GET '/remove' <function removeRoute at 0x00F5F420>>
Bottle v0.12.17 server starting up (using WSGIRefServer())...
Listening on http://localhost:8080/
Hit Ctrl-C to quit.

Routes after calling /add:
<GET '/add' <function addRoute at 0x02A876A8>>
<GET '/remove' <function removeRoute at 0x00F5F420>>
<GET '/route/hello' <function addRoute.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x030C3E88>>
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Aug/2020 23:19:09] "GET /add HTTP/1.1" 303 0
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Aug/2020 23:19:09] "GET /route/hello HTTP/1.1" 200 11
Routes after calling /remove:
<GET '/add' <function addRoute at 0x02A876A8>>
<GET '/remove' <function removeRoute at 0x00F5F420>>
<GET '/route/hello' <function addRoute.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x030C3E88>>
<GET '/route/hello' <function removeRoute.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x030C3FA8>>
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Aug/2020 23:19:14] "GET /remove HTTP/1.1" 303 0
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Aug/2020 23:19:14] "GET /route/hello HTTP/1.1" 404 720
Routes after calling /add:
<GET '/add' <function addRoute at 0x02A876A8>>
<GET '/remove' <function removeRoute at 0x00F5F420>>
<GET '/route/hello' <function addRoute.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x030C3E88>>
<GET '/route/hello' <function removeRoute.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x030C3FA8>>
<GET '/route/hello' <function addRoute.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x030E0270>>
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Aug/2020 23:19:17] "GET /add HTTP/1.1" 303 0
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Aug/2020 23:19:18] "GET /route/hello HTTP/1.1" 200 11
```

So instead of replacing **GET '/route/hello'**, the call: **app.route** adds more routes with the same **method** and **rule** on the end of the list.

However this worked so far, because the latest matching route one is choosen firstly, but I am pretty sure this would result (earlier or later) to performance problems or to a server crash after calling some **/add**s and **/remove**s.

Furthermore I noticed, that I can change **app.routes** without changing the actual routing, so **secondary question:**

**Could I just delete the 'deprecated' routes from app.routes to prevent a stackoverflow?**

And **third question:**

**Is there something I am doing in a completely wrong way?**

Comment: The `Bottle` object (often called `app`) holds the routes in a list as the `routes` attributes. You can manipulate it as you prefer.

Comment: I tried to manipulate the routes. It didn't do anything to the routing mechanism.

Comment: Nicely laid out question! Would you consider adding a word or two on _why_ you want to remove routes in the first place? The very fact that Bottle does not provide a method of doing so should be your first indication that maybe you're trying to solve the wrong problem. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked source code for [add_route](https://github.com/bottlepy/bottle/blob/master/bottle.py#L885)

It adds `route` to two objects: `self.routes` and `self.router` (`app.routes` and `app.router`) and this makes problem.

```
def add_route(self, route):
    """ Add a route object, but do not change the :data:`Route.app`
        attribute."""
    self.routes.append(route)
    self.router.add(route.rule, route.method, route, name=route.name)
    if DEBUG: route.prepare()
```

`self.router` is object [Router](https://github.com/bottlepy/bottle/blob/master/bottle.py#L307) which has `rules`, `builder`, `static`
`dyna_routes`, `dyna_regexes`

If you check them before and after adding new route then you see changes in `builder` and `static`.

```
def addRoute():
    print('--- before ---')
    print(app.router.rules)
    print(app.router.builder)
    print(app.router.static)
    print(app.router.dyna_routes)
    
    app.route('/route/hello')(lambda :'Hello World')

    print('--- after ---')
    print(app.router.rules)
    print(app.router.builder)
    print(app.router.static)
    print(app.router.dyna_routes)

    print('Routes after calling /add:\n' + '\n'.join([str(route) for route in app.routes]))
    redirect('route/hello')
```

If I remove `'/route/hello'` from `builder` and `static` then `'/route/hello'` stop working but `app.routes` still shows them so you will have to remove `'/route/hello'` from both `app.routes` and `app.router` - but they don't have special functions for this :)

```
def removeRoute():
    prefix = '/route/hello'

    del app.router.builder[prefix]
    del app.router.static['GET'][prefix]
    
    print('Routes after calling /remove:\n' + '\n'.join([str(route) for route in app.routes]))
    redirect('/route/hello')
```

---

My full code:

```
import bottle
from bottle import redirect, abort

def addRoute():
    print('--- before /add ---')
    print(app.router.rules)
    print(app.router.builder)
    print(app.router.static)
    print(app.router.dyna_routes)
    print(app.router.dyna_regexes)
    print('Routes before calling /add:\n' + '\n'.join([str(route) for route in app.routes]))
    
    app.route('/route/hello')(lambda :'Hello World')
    
    print('--- after /add ---')
    print(app.router.rules)
    print(app.router.builder)
    print(app.router.static)
    print(app.router.dyna_routes)
    print(app.router.dyna_regexes)
    print('Routes after calling /add:\n' + '\n'.join([str(route) for route in app.routes]))
    
    redirect('route/hello')

def removeRoute():
    prefix = '/route/hello'

    print('--- before /remove ---')
    print(app.router.rules)
    print(app.router.builder)
    print(app.router.static)
    print(app.router.dyna_routes)
    print(app.router.dyna_regexes)
    print('Routes before calling /remove:\n' + '\n'.join([str(route) for route in app.routes]))

    del app.router.builder[prefix]
    del app.router.static['GET'][prefix]
    
    print('--- after /remove ---')
    print(app.router.rules)
    print(app.router.builder)
    print(app.router.static)
    print(app.router.dyna_routes)
    print(app.router.dyna_regexes)
    print('Routes before calling /remove:\n' + '\n'.join([str(route) for route in app.routes]))

    redirect('/route/hello')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = bottle.app()
    app.route('/add')(addRoute)
    app.route('/remove')(removeRoute)
    print('Initial routes:\n' + '\n'.join([str(route) for route in app.routes]))
    bottle.run(app, host = 'localhost', port = 8080)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Btw: I did `app.routes = [route for route in app.routes if not(route.rule == prefix)]` after `del app.router.static['GET'][prefix]` to remove the route from **app.routes**